# Why doesn't this MySQL function work with VARCHAR parameters?

Tags: mysql, database, function, parameters

Why doesn't this MySQL function work with `VARCHAR` parameters? It works perfectly when parameter is removed

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION GETNAME(index varchar(30))

RETURNS varchar(50)

    BEGIN
        DECLARE fullname varchar(50);
        SELECT name into fullname from roles where roles.id = (select role_id from user_role where user_role.user_id = (select id from users where users.index_nb = index)) ;
        RETURN fullname;
    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: My guess would be that it is the name of the parameter causing you issues, not its type. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: Maybe name of parameter,  try @index

Comment: and not to mention the fact that you don't use stored procedures for simple queries like this

Comment: yeah it was...thanks :)